# Cypress + how to store a dynamic web element ID

Tags: cypress

Afternoon,

I need to be able to find and store an ID based on a text match.

So I'm able to find sometext and move to the parent div. But I need a way to store the ID but only the number as this will be chained into another action as this is dynamically built by the app and will defer radically.

source.

```
<div class="link name" role="button" tabindex="0" id="title-6126">
<p>sometext</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('div[role="button"]').invoke('attr', 'id').then((id) => {
  cy.log(+id.split('-')[1]) //prints 6126 as Number
  cy.wrap(+id.split('-')[1]).as('idNum') //To use later
})

cy.get('@idNum').then((idNum) => {
  cy.log(idNum) //prints 6126 as Number
  //Access idNum here
})
```

Now if you want to reach your id from your text, you can:

```js
cy.contains('sometext')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('div[role="button"]')
      .invoke('attr', 'id')
      .then((id) => {
        cy.log(+id.split('-')[1]) //prints 6126 as Number
        cy.wrap(+id.split('-')[1]).as('idNum') //To use later
      })
  })

cy.get('@idNum').then((idNum) => {
  cy.log(idNum) //prints 6126 as Number
  //Access idNum here
})
```